# Java: Long result = -1: cannot convert from int to long

Tags: java, casting

I'm using eclipse java ee to perform java programming.

I had the following line of code in one of my functions:

```
Long result = -1;
```

I got the following error:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to Long

I can't quite understand why when i add a number to the variable it provides this error.

How can this issue be resolved and why did it happen in the first place?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no conversion between the object `Long` and `int` so you need to make it from `long`. Adding a `L` makes the integer `-1` into a `long` (`-1L`):

```
Long result = -1L;
```

However there is a conversion from `int` a `long` so this works:

```
long result = -1;
```

Therefore you can write like this aswell:

```
Long result = (long) -1;
```

Converting from a primitive (`int`, `long` etc) to a Wrapper object (`Integer`, `Long` etc) is called autoboxing, read more [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html).

Comment: +1, and its important to be uppercase. `-1l` looks like `-11` :)

Answer (score 4):

`-1` can be auto-boxed to an Integer.

Thus:

```
Integer result = -1;
```

works and is equivalent to:

```
Integer result = Integer.valueOf(-1);
```

However, an Integer can't be assigned to a Long, so the overall conversion in the question fails.

```
Long result = Integer.valueOf(-1);
```

won't work either.

If you do:

```
Long result = -1L;
```

it's equivalent (again because of auto-boxing) to:

```
Long result = Long.valueOf(-1L);
```

Note that the `L` makes it a `long` literal.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, check you Java version: run "java -version" from command line.

In Java version prior to 1.5, the correct syntax is:

Long result = new Long(1L);

In java >1.5 it's done automatically. It's called "autoboxing".

The uppercase "L" tells Java that the number should be interpreted as long.

Comment: `Long.valueOf(1L);` is better than `new Long(1L);`, because it can give you a cached object. See API docs of `Long.valueOf(long)` for more information.

Answer (score 1):

```
Long result = -1L;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 Long result = -1L;

 Long result = (long) -1;

 Long result
     = Long.valueOf(-1);  // this is what auto-boxing does under the hood
```

How it happened in the first place is that the literal `-1` is an `int`. As of Java5, you can have it auto-boxed into an `Integer`, when you use it as on `Object`, but it will not be turned into a `Long` (only `long`s are).

Note that an int is automatically widened into a long when needed:

```
long result = -1;   // this is okay
```

The opposite way needs an explicit cast:

```
int number = (int) result;
```

Answer (score 1):

`-1` is a primitive int value, `Long` however is the wrapper class [`java.lang.Long`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html). An primitive integer value cannot be assigned to an Long object. There are two ways to solve this.

1. Change the type to `long`

   If you change the type from the wrapper class `Long` to the primitive type `long` java automatically casts the integer value to a long value.

   > `long result = -1;`
2. Change the int value to long

   If you change the integer value from `-1` to `-1L` to explicit change it to an long literal java can use this primitive value to automatically wrap this value to an `java.lang.Long` object.

   > `Long result = -1L;`

Answer (score 0):

To specify a constant of type `long`, suffix it with an `L`:

```
Long result = -1L;
```

Without the `L`, the interpreter types the constant number as an `int`, which is not the same type as a `long`.