# long and int same size in eclipse?

Tags: java

Don't know if this is an eclipse specific problem but whenever I declare a long and try to put a value > 2^32 in it complains about "the literal XXXXXX of type int is out of range"

I've tried casting is directly to long but is doesnt seem to have any effect. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try creating **long** constant: `123456789123l` (note letter `l` in the end)

```
long l = 123456789123; // error, constant `123456789123` has type int

long l1 = 123456789123l; // will work
long l2 = 123456789123L; // will work too
```

Comment: So there's no ambiguity, it's better to use capital 'L' exclusively.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437358/java-long-result-1-cannot-convert-from-int-to-long) . Don't be addictive to IDEs.

Comment: Slightly differently. That deals with implicit coercions from int (primitive) to Long (class type). The issue above is that that some numeric literals (say, 123456789123) are never valid as they exceed the range of an int. Java (unlike C#) won't "up-promote" numeric literals from int to long.

Comment: just want to show how "append" L to the end. same mistake because of IDE adiction I think. p.s I don't know C# :)