# Why doesn't Java support coercion and autoboxing?

Tags: java, autoboxing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java: Long result = -1: cannot convert from int to long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437358/java-long-result-1-cannot-convert-from-int-to-long)

For example `Integer foo = 4` and `Long foo = 4L` both compile, but `Long foo = 4` doesn't.  Is there a rationale for this?

Comment: Good question. I wonder if that would cause some ambiguities. (+1)

Comment: Technically, `Long foo = 4` can't be evaluated at compile time.

Comment: You mix up conversion with autoboxing.

Comment: @Bevor: can you explain what you mean by 'conversion'?

Comment: I don't mind if you want to close this as a duplicate, but deleting a comment suggesting that this /isn't/ a duplicate?  I was specifically looking for a *justification* of this behaviour, such as ambiguous cases that would be introduced as NPE mentions.

Comment: @hertzsprung I hope my comment was deleted automatically because it had link to possible duplicate. I vote to reopen it but it is probably too late to get more votes and more detailed answer.

Comment: @hertzsprung If it wasn't closed as duplicate, it would still be subject to closing under Not Constructive. StackOverflow is just not about questions that promote discussion instead of answering.

Comment: The JLS defines [nine boxing conversions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7) and "int to Long" is not among the list. "float to Double" like `Double d = 1.5f` won't work either. An automatic widening+boxing is simply not specified. It's by far easier to ask the programmer to cast then to specify all possible widening/narrowing+boxing/unboxing cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Long foo = 4;
```

means: assign an `int` of value 4 to a object of class `Long`. It will try to use autoboxing to do so and fail, because autoboxing is only applicable for the appropriate primitive. It can be fixed in two ways:

```
Long foo = (long) 4;
Long foo = 4L;
```

in the first case you cast the `int` 4 to `long` 4. In the second, you provide a long.

To answer the question: Java doesn't support auto-casting and is **very** strict in typing, which is probably why it doesn't support it automatically.