# Why is the default type of Java integer literals int instead of long?

Tags: java, integer, literals

I'm confused why Java integer literals default to `int` instead of `long`. This seems to cause unnecessary confusion.

First, it requires the programmer to adopt a special syntax (append "L" to literals) when assigning a value to a `long` that exceeds the maximum `int` size (2147483647).

```
long x = 2147483647; // Compiles
long y = 2147483648; // Does not compile
long z = 2147483648L; // Compiles
```

Second, when using the `Long` wrapper class, the programmer must always use the `long` literal notation as explained in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14425606/java-wrapper-classes-why-integer-literals-fail-for-long-but-work-for-smaller).

```
Long x = 250; // Does not compile
Long y = 250L; // Compiles
```

Third, considering that implicit conversion from `int` literals to the "narrower" data types (`short` and `byte`) works just fine in all situations (that I know of), it seems that simply making all integer literals type `long` would have been the obvious solution... right? Wouldn't this completely remove the need for this odd system of appending "L" to integer literals in special cases?

Comment: **tldr; Because this is how the Java languages (per the JLS) defines it.** In C#, this exact same syntax, "*automatically promotes*" the type of the literal - why do they differ? Ask the people who designed each respective language: as such, this sort of "*why*" speculation is generally Not Constructive. It is what it is.

Comment: @pst - java, being an older language, probably thought that promoting int to long is an expensive operation, so it shouldn't be done unless programmer explicitly requests it. c#, being a newer language, probably didn't think it's a big deal. This kind of reasoning *is* constructive to programmers, who are also designers at various levels.

Comment: @irreputable The promotion of a *literal integral* is a *compile time operation*. There is no "expense" here.

Comment: @pst, would you mind just submitting your own answer to the question?

Comment: @pst - this example is too simple. in general, the question is whether java should deduce the type of a literal based on context. that is achievable but more complex. java doesn't do that, so the type of a literal is fixed. java then adds some limited implicit conversions when it seems safe to do so. such conversions are runtime conversions.

Comment: @irreputable It's actually a good example and shows how Java treats int literals. It has nothing to do with context in this case  - type checking would have caught that (and type widening is actually used in the first declaration). In the case of "ambiguous" type widening such as overloads, this could have been well defined (as is done in C#). Granted, sometimes it *can* lead to tricky situations in C# (where it matters if the `short` or `int` overloads are called, for instance), but either approach is valid and can be argued for - there are worse things in modern languages, like `null` :D

Comment: @irreputable (Also, it is need *not* be a runtime conversion: for instance, the type of a literal - even that without a suffix - in C# is always fixed.)

Comment: I know this is a bit old but the answers below don't mention it. I wanted to point out that the language would be more difficult to parse if this were the case, because "int literal" vs "long literal" could no longer be easily defined by a simple grammar construct, the value would have to be calculated and checked by the parser which would then have to decide to promote the token from an int literal to a long literal. Implementing this is a bit of a kludge in a classic lex/parse parser. If I were designing a language I would make the same decision the Java designers did for this reason alone.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This behavior is by design<sup>1</sup> and is codified in the [JLS: Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/index.html).

First, note that this is *not* related to [widening](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2) which is why the (valid) integer-literal is promoted to a long value. Instead, this is related to the very specification of the [int literal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2):

> It is a compile-time error if a hexadecimal, octal, or binary int literal does not fit in 32 bits.

The smallest and largest signed 32-bit integer values are -2147483648 and 2147483647, respectively.

---

<sup>1</sup>I care not speculate on *why* it works this way, and languages like C# have different rules.

Comment: Can I get a check this? The specification also makes reference to: "It is a compile-time error if a decimal literal of type int is larger than 2147483648 (2^31)", which leaves me confused.

Comment: you've answered my question by concluding that the best we can do is speculate as to why the language works this way. Thankfully, I found some of the speculation in other people's answers insightful, but ultimately it seems there is no dominant logic behind what appears to be a mere design decision.

Comment: Note however, that `-2147483648` is not an `int` literal. This is a unary minus, followed by the literal `2147483648`.

Answer (score 3):

Speed

You have efficiency gains by only using the size that you need. An int is fine for numbers from -2^31 to 2^31. If you use a long where an int would suffice, you slow down your code. For example, this code runs at 7.116 seconds on my machine. By switching it to using int, I decrease the running time to 3.74 seconds on my machine:

```
public class Problem005 {

  private static boolean isDivisibleByAll(long n, long ceiling) {
    for (long i = 1; i < ceiling; i++)
      if (n % i != 0)
        return false;
    return true;
  }

  public static long findSmallestMultiple (long ceiling) {
    long number = 1;
    while (!isDivisibleByAll(number, ceiling))
      number++;
    return number;
  }

}

public class Stopwatch {
  private final long start;

  public Stopwatch() {
    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
  }

  public double elapsedTime() {
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    return (now - start) / 1000.0;
  }

}

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Stopwatch stopwatch005 = new Stopwatch();

    long highestMultiple = 20;
    long findSmallestMultipleOutput = findSmallestMultiple(highestMultiple);
    double findSmallestMultipleTime = stopwatch005.elapsedTime();
    System.out.println("Problem #005");
    System.out.println("============");
    System.out.print("The multiple of the numbers 1-" + highestMultiple + " is = ");
    System.out.print(findSmallestMultipleOutput);
    System.out.println(" with a time of " + findSmallestMultipleTime + " seconds.\n ");
  }   
}
```

### Changed to use int:

```
public class Problem005 {

  private static boolean isDivisibleByAll(int n, int ceiling) {
    for (int i = 1; i < ceiling; i++)
      if (n % i != 0)
        return false;
    return true;
  }

  public static int findSmallestMultiple (int ceiling) {
    int number = 1;
    while (!isDivisibleByAll(number, ceiling))
      number++;
    return number;
  }

}
```

Comment: would it make a difference if RAM cells were 64 bits?

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question the question.

Comment: The question is "why doesn't an int literal get promoted to a long"; the target variable it a `long`.

Comment: @G.Bach if I change the loop to use byte instead of int, there is a slight performance uptick, speed goes down to 3.687.

Comment: @pst my point is that if an int would default to a promotion of long, the default promotion would result in less efficient code by default in many cases.

Comment: No, it would not. Given `long x = /* any integral value represented by a long */`, `x++` has the exact same "performance". The question is about why there is a compiler error when using an integral literal (*not* suffixed with `L`) that is *not* in the range of values representable by `int`. In C# this is *not* an error.

Comment: @pst the OP states, "simply making all integer literals type long would have been the obvious solution". I understand this to mean that java would just use long instead of int/long. A consequence of this, I believe, would be that code would run more slowly, as is the case in the code I posted.

Comment: Please look at the types used. There is *no* `int`-typed variable in the posted question. As such, I believe that reading is inaccurate.

Comment: @pst i see, said the blind man :)

Comment: @pst definitely has the correct interpretation of the question.

Comment: @pst you haven't made a post yet, and already you have my vote

Answer (score 3):

One of the possible reasons that `int` is default literal is that using `long` could cause hard to detect errors in multi-threading application, as specified in [JLS 17.7 Non-atomic Treatment of double and long](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.7).

> For the purposes of the Java programming language memory model, a single write to a **non-volatile** long or double value is treated as two separate writes: one to each 32-bit half. This can result in a situation where a thread sees the first 32 bits of a 64-bit value from one write, and the second 32 bits from another write.

Comment: double is also 64 bit. but double is usually well supported by CPU's floating point unit. so it's probably more about computation speed, instead of word tearing.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are right, `long` would be a better default today. Back in 1995, `long` was probably too long to be the default.

Comment: This is an intriguing answer that sounds like it might be true, but do we have any proof? Is there somewhere online where we can read the original Java language specification?

Comment: on a 32 bit machine, long is obviously much slower. you need 2 registers to hold it.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, however. The question isn't about `int` vs. `long`, it is related to why an integral literal inside the range of `long` but *outside* the range of `int` require the `L` suffice to avoid a syntax error. And the answer is because: that's how Java works.

Comment: @pst - well the title is questioning why `long` isn't the default literal type. we all read questions slightly differently, that's ok. though I'm not providing a full answer, I concur with part of questioner's premise, that is, `long` seems to be a better default, and suggests that the reason might be historical.

Answer (score 0):

For the

```
Long x = 250;
```

That won't work. Java uses Autoboxing, which casts automatically from the Object representative class to the primitive type. As for the other ones, int's are just the primary number type used. Longs, well at least for what I use them most often for, are used for dates and times only. Integers on the other hand are used by default for everything else.

If you really want to get into specifics, I'm sure this will rustle your jimmies more:

```
float pi = 3.14; // Does not compile.
float pi = 3.14F; // Compiles
```

In this case as well, double takes the priority when there is a decimal involved.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason for making int literals the ones that don't need a type indication is that int is intended to be the normal integer type. Similarly, double is the normal floating point type. The idea seems to be to limit the number of literals that need a type indication by defaulting to the commonest type.

Answer (score 0):

It would be possible for a language to require that all integer arithmetic which would not overflow if intermediate results were computed with the longest integral type, as though they were.  In such a language, if variables starting with L are 64 bits, those with W are 32-bits, and those with H are 16 bits, expressions like

```
L1 = W1*W2;
W3 = (W1+W2) >> 1
```

will be evaluated in such fashion as to avoid overflow, but an expression like

```
W4 = W1+W2
```

will be evaluated using 32-bit math (since any overflow that would occur then would occur with the assignment to W4 even if the intermediate result were evaluated as 32 bits), and an expression like

```
W5 = (H1*H2) >> 1
```

could be evaluated as 32 bits since the result couldn't overflow a 32-bit value.

Such a language could be quite efficient in most scenarios, since it would generally not hard for a compiler to determine the maximum relevant integer size for each subexpression.  In such a language, it wouldn't matter whether a numeric literal was a "long" or an "int", since the compiler would be more interested in its numeric value.

In Java, however, numeric literals of different sizes have different semantics.  If one multiplies an `int` by the constant 128, the `int` must be no larger than 16,777,215 or else an overflow will occur.  If one multiplies the `int` by a constant `128L`, the result may only be stored someplace that can accept a `long`.