# Java autoboxing int to Long

Tags: java, casting, autoboxing

Why can't the Java compiler directly cast an `int` to a `Long`?

```
long test = 1; // ok
Long test2 = 2; // does not compile!
Long test3 = 3L; // ok
```

It's especially frustrating since (of course) one can do

```
long test = 1;    
Long test2 = test;
```

Is it a deliberate design choice? What could go wrong if this was allowed?

Comment: For `Long test2 = 2;` to work, 2 implicit conversions would be required (`int` to `long` then `long` to `Long`). What do you think about that?

Comment: @ernest_k I'd be completely fine with that!

Comment: To make it even worse, this compiles: `Short test4 = 4;`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14425606/wrapper-classes-why-integer-literals-fail-for-long-but-work-for-anything-small

Comment: @Thilo all the more reason to be consistent and allow it also for widening. In addition shortening is generally unsafe.

Answer (score 1):

An `int` is a primitive data type in Java. `long` is a primitive data type too, but `Long` is not a primitive data type. 
The implicit conversion does not work that way. You have to explicitly tell Java to convert to an object of type `Long`.

It is possible to implicitly cast a `long` to a `Long` because it is a single implicit conversion. From `int` to `Long` would be two conversions in one step which is not supported.

For the integer suffix syntax `100L` see [JLS 3.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10). The `L` sets the type of the value to `long`instead of int, which is the default case for integral types.

Comment: I already noticed that it's not supported, my question was why.

Comment: And I explained that it is because of two implicit conversions in one step which cannot be done and is not specified.

Comment: Hmm. `Short test4 = 4` is also two conversions, and that is allowed.

Comment: Yes, because it is a narrowing step.

Comment: In general, Java forbids two conversions in a single step. That's the reason why it does not work for Long. It is a bad design decision to allow it for narrowing conversions, I don't think there is a real reason behind that.

Comment: Not for all narrowing conversions, though: `Integer test5 = 5L;` does not compile. :-) I think we can all agree that the rules are pretty rough, probably because this was bolted on later in life (with Java5).