# add and re-use long numbers to/from android resources

Tags: android, xml

I have a constant long number  `REFRESH_TIME`.

```
long REFRESH_TIME=24;
```

(i gave it `24` but it must be `long` and i don't want use `int` to `long` type conversion!)

How i could save this long type number in resources (xml resource file ) and re-use it as a long number in my android app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are all the resource types you have in android: [Resource Types](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/available-resources.html) and [More Resource Types](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html).

The closest you have is `Integer` (nothing specific for just long), so i don't think you can get rid of the casting int to long.

Best you can do is find a optimal way for casting it. Answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437358/java-long-result-1-cannot-convert-from-int-to-long) lists several different ways to do that.

Comment: +1 Thanks. If there is no native `long` support in resource file,so maybe I use  a `String` and cast it to `long`. (surely for this one `int` would be much better to cast to `long`)